# Error when uploading new version of Magento extension on connect manager

Tags: magento

I'm getting following error when uploading new version of Magento (community edition) module.

> Unable to convert PEAR package to Magento package format. Recheck package.xml file.

Please suggest how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: You mean to say you are trying to install an extension via magento connect manager is it so ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

please close this question. I have solved it already. We need to create package via magento admin before submitting it to magento connect.